# select the value from ul-li dropdown in protractor

Tags: protractor

[element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHna3.png)i want to select a 3rd value from the drop down of 6 options and the code snippet for a single option as below: the div class is under the li class.

RELV-Indirect Tax

RELV-Indirect Tax

i dont want to select by id instead i want to pass the value as "RELV-Indirect Tax". how to do the same?

Comment: <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable ng-scope ng-binding" role="presentation"><div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-12" role="option"><span class="select2-match"></span>RELV-Indirect Tax</div></li>

Comment: <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-12" role="option"><span class="select2-match"></span>RELV-Indirect Tax</div>

Comment: It would be good if you inspect the element and attach a screenshot.

Comment: kishan, attached the same. refer element.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code and let me know.
Clicking on the `dropdown` will work for you I guess.

```
var selectdropdown = element(by.xpath("//select[@id='TaxProcessMod']")); 
selectdropdown.click();
selectdropdown.all(by.xpath("//option[@class='ng-scope ng-binding']")).get(1).click();
```

> OR

```
selectdropdown.all(by.className("ng-scope ng-binding")).get(1).click();
```

Comment: the above was throwing error. i have added as below and it is working. 
       var selectdropdown = element(by.xpath("//select[@id='TaxProcessMod']"));
selectdropdown.click();
        element.all(by.repeater("item in taxProcessDropdown | filter: {value: '!All'}")).get(1).click();

Comment: I would recommend you to go through class and not by `item in taxProcessDropdown | filter: {value: '!All'}`

Comment: Do have a look at my edited answer. It is more simpler

Comment: oh is it?i always gives preference to protractor elements if not available, i will go for other one. since by.repeater is available, i have used it. Is this not a good approach? since i m new to protractor, please guide me

Comment: All `ng` tags are good but the content is a bit messy `item in taxProcessDropdown | filter: {value: '!All'`, that is the reason I am telling you to go for class. Protractor is inherited from selenium only so there are no issues to use the class.